# jQuery: How to count result from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am returning a JSON array for a project.   Here's what the response looks like:

```
{"data":[{"DT_RowId":"row_60","contacts":{"first_name":"Screech","last_name":"Powers"},"users_todos":{"text":"whowho","due_date":"Wed, Feb 6 2019","company_id":"1","location_id":"15","assigned_to_user_id":"21","assigned_to_contact_id":"4258","inserted_by_user_id":"15","status_id":"0"}}],"options":[],"files":[]}


data: [{DT_RowId: "row_60", contacts: {first_name: "Screech", last_name: 
     "Powers"},…}]
   0: {DT_RowId: "row_60", contacts: {first_name: "Screech", last_name: 
     "Powers"},…}
      DT_RowId: "row_60"
      contacts: {first_name: "Screech", last_name: "Powers"}
           first_name: "Screech"
           last_name: "Powers"
      users_todos: {text: "whowho", due_date: "Wed, Feb 6 2019", company_id: 
       "1", location_id: "15",…}
            assigned_to_contact_id: "4258"
            assigned_to_user_id: "21"
            company_id: "1"
            due_date: "Wed, Feb 6 2019"
            inserted_by_user_id: "15"
            location_id: "15"
            status_id: "0"
            text: "whowho"
   files: []
   options: []
```

I am trying to return a function that will count how many of the results have users_todos -> status_id = 'value' and then put that into a label elsewhere on the page.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function count_category(category, json) {

var count= 0;
$.each(json, function (k , v) {
    if (v['users_todos']['status_id'] === category) {
        count++;
    }
});

return count;

};

$('.user_todos_incomplete_count').text('(' + count_category('0', json['data']) + ')');

$('#user_todos_in_progress_count').text('(' + count_category('1', json['data']) + ')');

$('#user_todos_complete_count').text('(' + count_category('2', json['data']) + ')');

$('#user_todos_disregarded_count').text('(' + count_category('3', json['data']) + ')');
```

I am currently getting a count of 0 for all _count values.   It seems like I'm missing the proper way to detect the status_id values from the JSON response.

Comment: what is 'all _count' ? is that sum of all or specific field?

Comment: Sorry, Andy. My mistake:  I didn't mean to have the underscore.   I was just referring to all of my count requests.

Comment: is 'users_todos' field present in all rows or it's null?

Comment: It is present in all rows.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use array filter method , which will return an array of matched elements. Then use `length` property to get the value

```js
let dt = {
  "data": [{
    "DT_RowId": "row_60",
    "contacts": {
      "first_name": "Screech",
      "last_name": "Powers"
    },
    "users_todos": {
      "text": "whowho",
      "due_date": "Wed, Feb 6 2019",
      "company_id": "1",
      "location_id": "15",
      "assigned_to_user_id": "21",
      "assigned_to_contact_id": "4258",
      "inserted_by_user_id": "15",
      "status_id": "0"
    }
  }],
  "options": [],
  "files": []
}


function getCount(cat) {
  return dt.data.filter(elem => elem.users_todos.status_id === cat).length

}

console.log(getCount('0'))
```

Comment: Use ES6 everwwhere and make it a one-liner :) `const getCount = cat => dt.data.filter(elem => elem.users_todos.status_id === cat).length`

Comment: This is a much neater approach to the general algorithm, but I think it misses the point that the original code in the question will already work as long as the data provided has been parsed from JSON into a variable. Once that's done, OP's code does the job. So if they try your code, they will likely face the same issue until they've parsed the data.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you parse your JSON into a JavaScript object first, then your code should work - it will return `1` for the first count, which is correct based on the sample data provided.

Just ensure you used JSON.parse() to import the JSON first, otherwise you're dealing with a string, and not an object.

```js
function count_category(category, json) {

  var count = 0;
  $.each(json, function(k, v) {
    if (v['users_todos']['status_id'] === category) {
      count++;
    }
  });

  return count;

};

var rawjson = '{"data":[{"DT_RowId":"row_60","contacts":{"first_name":"Screech","last_name":"Powers"},"users_todos":{"text":"whowho","due_date":"Wed, Feb 6 2019","company_id":"1","location_id":"15","assigned_to_user_id":"21","assigned_to_contact_id":"4258","inserted_by_user_id":"15","status_id":"0"}}],"options":[],"files":[]}';

var json = JSON.parse(rawjson);

console.log('(' + count_category('0', json['data']) + ')');
console.log('(' + count_category('1', json['data']) + ')');
console.log('(' + count_category('2', json['data']) + ')');
console.log('(' + count_category('3', json['data']) + ')');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you fail to parse the JSON and just run your code against the raw JSON string, it produces 0 for all counts, as you reported in your question.

N.B. There are definitely more efficient ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but my point is that there's nothing inherently broken about your code, apart from possibly not parsing your JSON.

Comment: that `data` is already parsed because it's simply response, i believe so

Comment: @Andy if that's was the case then the code should already work as shown in the question. But OP says it doesn't...so this is my assumption. And for sure if you run the same code on the raw JSON without parsing it, you can 0 for all counts as the OP reports (I tested). Anyway, whether the response to an ajax call is automatically parsed into JSON depends on the settings used when making the call, and/or headers returned by the server etc. It's not guaranteed.

Comment: that's correct. we definitely must to use object nut not the its string representation. According to the facing problem there is no ability to simply calculate total rows that contain `users_todos` field.

Comment: @Andy "According to the facing problem there is no ability to simply calculate total rows that contain users_todos field." ....sorry I'm not sure what point you are making here? I don't really understand your comment. Can you re-phrase it? The code above in my answer works and gets the number of status IDs matching each value.

Comment: and I don't understand what exactly you don't get it. Your code works to get count by specific category only. I believe that now you got what I'm trying to convey to you

Comment: @Andy "Your code works to get count by specific category only" . So what? That's what the OP wants. You can see in the original he has different places in the page to display each output from each different category. Searching by a specific category is necessary to achieve that. Anyway, it's really not _my_ code, it's identical to the OP's apart from one line which was missing - to parse the JSON.

Comment: ADyson - there is not a problem to get count by category. there is a problem to get all count. Please read problem till the end.

Comment: @ADyson: If I may put my two cents... I suggest this update to your code: `var json = (typeof(rawjson) == "string") ? JSON.parse(rawjson) : rawjson;` -- And I don't get Andy's point either.

Comment: @Andy "there is a problem to get all count." ...no..you've misunderstood what the phrase means in the question. OP is saying that all the results return 0, when really the first result should be 1. The code is not even attempting to count them all at once. There is nowhere in the UI to put such a result either. Maybe it's just the language barrier but I think you have mis-interpreted what OP is saying. You can always ask him to clarify of course.

Comment: I asked him that thing but nothing answered yet

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I see what you're saying but actually I'm sure in the real world the data will arrive consistently as either JSON or already-parsed data. It won't vary, I would hope. So OP should know (once they check) what format the data is always in when it gets to this part of the code. I don't think it should be necessary to test it every time....but maybe there's a situation where that would be beneficial.

Comment: @Andy actually you did get a response but OP misunderstood _you_ and thought you were asking about the `_` character in his text. Perhaps you need to ask again in a different way. Although he did also say " I was just referring to all of my count requests"...which I think backs up my interpretation.

Comment: The data was already parsed I believe, so parsing it again didn't help.  I do appreciate the help here though fronm everyone.  I was able to use brk's answer so I can get the counts on status_id when it's = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.  And, I learned something.  Thanks again.

The way I had it, it wasn't counting anything I suppose and returning 0 all the time.

Comment: @chris.cavage but if you run my example, with parsed data, you get 1 for the first result. You only get all 0s if your data isn't parsed (I tested it). So I don't understand how you can be saying your data was parsed but you got 0s in the output. Your statement doesn't match what the code is doing.

Comment: @chris.cavage here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k3frzmu5/ showing what happens if the data is an unparsed JSON string. All 0s in the console. And here it is again (just like my snippet above) where the data gets parsed first: https://jsfiddle.net/k3frzmu5/1/ . You get 1 for the first result. And lastly here it is when the data is supplied as an object literal to begin with - again you get 1 for the first result. https://jsfiddle.net/k3frzmu5/2/ . The only case you get all 0s is where the data is not properly parsed first. Unless you can prove to me otherwise with a runnable example??

Comment: @chris.cavage the only other possible reason I can think of for what you're saying is if the data you're testing with isn't the same as that shown in your question, and it actually doesn't contain any of your category values at all. But that doesn't make the code in my answer incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Well, to count all rows that have `user_todos` you need another function like this one:

```
function count_all(json) {
  return json.filter(function(row) {
    return row.users_todos).length;
  }
}
```

Comment: "to count all rows that have user_todos" ...that's not what the code is trying to do. Read the question more carefully.